# How can I compensate for an apparent SSL chain mismatch in Jsoup?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jsoup

I'm requesting a webpage with the following code:

```
Jsoup.connect(url)
     .method(Connection.Method.GET)
     .execute()
```

The site I'm attempting to scrape shows the following certification path in Chrome:

```
1) ***REDACTED***
Issued by DigiCert Global CA G2

2) DigiCert Global CA G2
Issued by DigiCert Global Root G2

3) DigiCert Global Root G2
Issued by DigiCert Global Root G2
```

Running my program with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` shows this chain:

```
1) ***REDACTED***
Issued by DigiCert Global CA G2

2) Symantec Class 3 Secure Server SHA256 SSL CA
Issued by VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority

3) VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority
Issued by VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority
```

The result is a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. Testing the server in [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) shows the correct chain under "Certification Paths" and the broken one under "Additional Certificates (if supplied)", with "Incomplete, Extra certs, Contains anchor" listed as chain issues. I have no desire to use validateTLSCertificates(false) unless absolutely necessary.

How can I ensure that Jsoup follows the correct certification path instead of getting distracted by the erroneous extra certificate?

Comment: Make sure you are using SNI. Nowadays many TLS servers, specially HTTPS one, sit on one IP but multiple names, so the certificates (and the whole TLS exchange) that the server will send back to client will depend on which hostname the client requested, as forwarded in the SNI extension.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Is SNI automatic with JVM 1.8 and Jsoup 1.11.3?